# How to create https endpoints for Azure Service Fabric on local machine using HttpSys?

Tags: azure, https, azure-service-fabric, endpoint

I'm trying to create https endpoints for three apps in a cluster of Service Fabric. Because I have more than one app I use HttpSys. So far I worked only on http but requests from frontend are from a secure transmission(https) so I have to put my backend on https.

I tried to follow this [1](https://dzimchuk.net/setting-up-https-endpoints-in-asp-net-core-services-in-service-fabric/) but it doesn't work with WebListener so I move the implementation to HttpSys.
I don't have any errors and my cluster is working well but when I try to access my https endpoint I get nothing.

Comment: Did you tried using kestrel with https certificate instead?

Comment: Yes and this works well, but I need HttpSys configuration. I resolved this locally and it works well with a generated certificated. I wil be back with an article on medium or something like that because I haven't found something similar. Also now I'am trying to put it on azure but I have some problems. Cluster is on but I can't get to endpoint. I suspect that vms isn't configure well. Do you have any ideas about it ?

Comment: You need to create a policy in load balancer to open the target port your application is working on

Comment: I have tried this but it isn't working..Can I show you some configuration ?

Comment: Hey @MocanuGabriel Do you find any solution? although microsoft recommend to use kestrel.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find any option.